# How to create a SQL Query to Join 2 tables after 2 different Rules

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a SQL query in `SQL Server Management Studio 19.1`  where I want to combine the `AAPL_265598_30min` table to the `AAPL_265598_15min` table after 2 rules. (See the 2 tables below)

**Table: "AAPL_265598_15min"**

| DateTime | MonthNr | DayNr | roc_1 | roc_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-02-13 17:15:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.507496097322141 | -0.447054112290804 |
| 2013-02-13 17:30:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.228570816282782 | -0.73490692563267 |
| 2013-02-13 17:45:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.175177316723154 | -0.403347728783159 |
| 2013-02-13 18:00:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.0488880377329933 | -0.223979713703448 |
| 2013-02-13 18:15:00 | 2 | 3 | 0.107008341975564 | 0.0580679899639679 |
| 2013-02-13 18:30:00 | 2 | 3 | 0.204186540033735 | 0.311413378640326 |
| 2013-02-13 18:45:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.484620355253855 | -0.281423344755812 |
| 2013-02-13 19:00:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.146136764079756 | -0.630048910828371 |
| 2013-02-13 19:15:00 | 2 | 3 | 0.0567832204194419 | -0.0894365248211751 |

**Table: "AAPL_265598_30min"**

| DateTime | MonthNr | DayNr | roc_1 | roc_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-02-13 16:30:00 | 2 | 3 | ,0.615501414697727 | ,1.19568853721923 |
| 2013-02-13 17:00:00 | 2 | 3 | ,-0.447054112290804 | 0.165695678021309 |
| 2013-02-13 17:30:00 | 2 | 3 | ,-0.403347728783159 | -0.848598658465607 |
| 2013-02-13 18:00:00 | 2 | 3 | ,0.0580679899639679 | -0.345513954737861 |
| 2013-02-13 18:30:00 | 2 | 3 | ,-0.281423344755812 | -0.223518771671433 |
| 2013-02-13 19:00:00 | 2 | 3 | ,-0.0894365248211751 | -0.370608174317402 |

The 2 rules are as follows:

1. In the Joined table, the values of `roc_1` and `roc_2` from the `AAPL_265598_30min` table should be added where the `DateTime` in that table is <= 30 minutes than it is in the `AAPL_265598_15min` table.
2. Only the FIRST occurrence where `DateTime` in `AAPL_265598_30min` table <= 30 minutes than `DateTime` in `AAPL_265598_15min` table.

**The Joined Table should then look like this:**

| DateTime | MonthNr | DayNr | roc_1 | roc_2 | roc_1 | roc_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-02-13 17:15:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.507496097322141 | -0.447054112290804 | 0.615501414697727 | 1.19568853721923 |
| 2013-02-13 17:30:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.228570816282782 | -0.73490692563267 | -0.447054112290804 | 0.165695678021309 |
| 2013-02-13 17:45:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.175177316723154 | -0.403347728783159 | -0.447054112290804 | 0.165695678021309 |
| 2013-02-13 18:00:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.0488880377329933 | -0.223979713703448 | -0.403347728783159 | -0.848598658465607 |
| 2013-02-13 18:15:00 | 2 | 3 | 0.107008341975564 | 0.0580679899639679 | -0.403347728783159 | -0.848598658465607 |
| 2013-02-13 18:30:00 | 2 | 3 | 0.204186540033735 | 0.311413378640326 | 0.0580679899639679 | -0.345513954737861 |
| 2013-02-13 18:45:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.484620355253855 | -0.281423344755812 | 0.0580679899639679 | -0.345513954737861 |
| 2013-02-13 19:00:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.146136764079756 | -0.630048910828371 | -0.281423344755812 | -0.223518771671433 |
| 2013-02-13 19:15:00 | 2 | 3 | 0.0567832204194419 | -0.0894365248211751 | -0.281423344755812 | -0.223518771671433 |

I am trying with this Query but it produces duplicate rows:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2000
    AAPL_265598_15min.DateTime AS AAPL_265598_15min_DateTime, 
    AAPL_265598_15min.MonthNr AS AAPL_265598_15min_MonthNr, 
    AAPL_265598_15min.DayNr AS AAPL_265598_15min_DayNr, 
    AAPL_265598_15min.roc_1 AS AAPL_265598_15min_roc_1, 
    AAPL_265598_15min.roc_2 AS AAPL_265598_15min_roc_2, 
    AAPL_265598_15min.hypo_upordown7bars AS Label,
    AAPL_265598_30min.MonthNr AS AAPL_265598_30min_MonthNr, 
    AAPL_265598_30min.DayNr AS AAPL_265598_30min_DayNr, 
    AAPL_265598_30min.roc_1 AS AAPL_265598_30min_roc_1, 
    AAPL_265598_30min.roc_2 AS AAPL_265598_30min_roc_2 
FROM 
    AAPL_265598_15min, AAPL_265598_30min
WHERE 
        AAPL_265598_15min.DateTime IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_15min.MonthNr IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_15min.DayNr IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_15min.roc_1 IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_15min.roc_2 IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_30min.MonthNr IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_30min.DayNr IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_30min.roc_1 IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_30min.roc_2 IS NOT NULL 
    AND AAPL_265598_15min.hypo_upordown7bars IS NOT NULL
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, AAPL_265598_30min.DateTime, AAPL_265598_15min.DateTime) >= 30
```

That Query Produces duplicate rows like this and not correct `roc_1` and `roc_2` values from `AAPL_265598_30min` table which is the problem where I don't know what I need to do with the query to make it work correctly?

| DateTime | MonthNr | DayNr | roc_1 | roc_2 | roc_1 | roc_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-02-13 17:15:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.507496097322141 | -0.447054112290804 | 0.615501414697727 | 1.19568853721923 |
| 2013-02-13 17:30:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.228570816282782 | -0.73490692563267 | -0.447054112290804 | 0.165695678021309 |
| 2013-02-13 17:30:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.228570816282782 | -0.73490692563267 | 0.615501414697727 | 1.19568853721923 |
| 2013-02-13 17:45:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.175177316723154 | -0.403347728783159 | -0.447054112290804 | 0.165695678021309 |
| 2013-02-13 17:45:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.175177316723154 | -0.403347728783159 | 0.615501414697727 | 1.19568853721923 |
| 2013-02-13 18:00:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.0488880377329933 | -0.223979713703448 | -0.403347728783159 | -0.848598658465607 |
| 2013-02-13 18:00:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.0488880377329933 | -0.223979713703448 | -0.447054112290804 | 0.165695678021309 |
| 2013-02-13 18:00:00 | 2 | 3 | -0.0488880377329933 | -0.223979713703448 | 0.615501414697727 | 1.19568853721923 |

Comment: Hi 1) please format your data as tables so that it’s readable

Comment: Yes, I am doing that all the time now. I could see it looked bad. Still trying to fix it.

Comment: You want a row_number() or APPLY operation instead of a simple JOIN. Also, **NEVER** use the A,B join syntax. It's been obsolete for **30 years** now.

Comment: Also, we can infer SQL Server from the C# string syntax, but that's gone now because it wasn't otherwise relevant to the question and it was never a sure thing to begin with. Instead, you should tag the question to include the specific type and version of database you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 2000
    AAPL_265598_15min_DateTime, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_MonthNr, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_DayNr, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_roc_1, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_roc_2, 
    Label,
    AAPL_265598_30min_MonthNr, 
    AAPL_265598_30min_DayNr, 
    AAPL_265598_30min_roc_1, 
    AAPL_265598_30min_roc_2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        m15.DateTime AS AAPL_265598_15min_DateTime, 
        m15.MonthNr AS AAPL_265598_15min_MonthNr, 
        m15.DayNr AS AAPL_265598_15min_DayNr, 
        m15.roc_1 AS AAPL_265598_15min_roc_1, 
        m15.roc_2 AS AAPL_265598_15min_roc_2, 
        m15.hypo_upordown7bars AS Label,
        m30.MonthNr AS AAPL_265598_30min_MonthNr, 
        m30.DayNr AS AAPL_265598_30min_DayNr, 
        m30.roc_1 AS AAPL_265598_30min_roc_1, 
        m30.roc_2 AS AAPL_265598_30min_roc_2,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY m15.DateTime ORDER BY m30.DateTime) rn 
    FROM 
        AAPL_265598_15min m15
    INNER JOIN AAPL_265598_30min m30 ON 
            m30.DateTime >= m15.DateTime 
        AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, m30.DateTime, m15.DateTime) <= 30
    WHERE 
            m15.DateTime IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.MonthNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.DayNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.roc_1 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.roc_2 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.MonthNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.DayNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.roc_1 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.roc_2 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.hypo_upordown7bars IS NOT NULL
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

It uses the `PARTITION BY` feature in the `row_number()` windowing function to number rows for each new `DateTime` from the 15 minute table, and then nests the query to filter for the first row only (`rn=1`) from each group (the nesting is needed since SQL Server does not yet support `QUALIFY` outside of Azure).

You could also accomplish this via an `APPLY` operation (as I indicated in an earlier comment), which I often find easier to write and maintain. But in my experience so far the `row_number()` solution tends to perform better.

Separately, this fixes of number of outdated practices from the original code and brings it up closer to modern standards, including explicit JOIN definitions and column aliases.

Comment: I am quite new to SQL. The query took 27 minutes to run on 2000 rows. Does that sound correct. It sounds quite long? The query seems to do almost correct. It seems that the DateTime from the 30min table is out of sync where it takes a DateTime in the future by 15 minutes and less. Otherwise it seems to be close. I wonder a bit for the 27 minutes if it sounds normal?

Comment: I change to this where m30 must have a less DateTime: `m30.DateTime < m15.DateTime` but it is still out of sync for 1 record. It is very close to be correct. Not it took 2 minutes to run the query.

Comment: 27 minutes is way too long. Two minutes is also kind of long, but can be correct depending on the size of the data and server capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you will be picking the closest one from 30min table:

```
SELECT A.*,
       matched_result.roc_1,
       matched_result.roc_2
FROM #AAPL_265598_15min as A 
OUTER APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 *
 FROM #AAPL_265598_30min as B
 WHERE B.DayNr = A.DayNr
   AND B.MonthNr = A.MonthNr
   AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE,B.[DateTime],A.[DateTime]) <= 30
 ORDER By B.[DateTime] DESC  --change this to 'ASC' or remove the 'DESC' if you want to match the earliest one from 30Min to 15Min table
) as matched_result
ORDER BY A.[DateTime]
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the query. It seems to get correct value from the 30min table for 1 record when the 15min table has date for example: 2013-02-27 18:00:00. Then it takes the value of 2013-02-27 17:30:00 from the 30min table.<br>

But it still takes the value of 2013-02-27 17:30:00 from the 30min table when  the 15min table has date: 2013-02-27 17:45:00 where it is only 15 minutes DATEDIFF. Here it should take the value from 2013-02-27 17:00:00.

Comment: I might forgot to mention that B.DayNr = A.DayNr AND B.MonthNr = A.MonthNr should not be there as it can search for the first occurence of any DateTime which is <= 30 min.

Comment: if you only need the record having 30 mins gap to be matched, can just change AND `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,B.[DateTime],A.[DateTime]) <= 30` to `=30`. regarding the joins based on Day and Month, not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, but to me, it would be making more sense if the record are from the same day so you could see the last one 30 mins ago?

Comment: It is stock market data. So I try to catch the last 30 minute bar which not always is exactly = 30 if there is gap in the data. I then try to catch the bars which satisfies the condition <= 30 which also means that for each day, I would need to catch the 30min data which is the day before. So there `B.DayNr = A.DayNr AND B.MonthNr = A.MonthNr` will not be true once per day.

Answer (score 0):

With Joel Coehoorn code and explanation, I came up which seems to do the correct results which is the query below. Thanks for the help!

```
SELECT TOP 2000
    AAPL_265598_15min_DateTime, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_MonthNr, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_DayNr, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_roc_1, 
    AAPL_265598_15min_roc_2, 
    Label,
    AAPL_265598_30min_MonthNr, 
    AAPL_265598_30min_DayNr, 
    AAPL_265598_30min_roc_1, 
    AAPL_265598_30min_roc_2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        m15.DateTime AS AAPL_265598_15min_DateTime, 
        m15.MonthNr AS AAPL_265598_15min_MonthNr, 
        m15.DayNr AS AAPL_265598_15min_DayNr, 
        m15.roc_1 AS AAPL_265598_15min_roc_1, 
        m15.roc_2 AS AAPL_265598_15min_roc_2, 
        m15.hypo_upordown7bars AS Label,
        m30.MonthNr AS AAPL_265598_30min_MonthNr, 
        m30.DayNr AS AAPL_265598_30min_DayNr, 
        m30.roc_1 AS AAPL_265598_30min_roc_1, 
        m30.roc_2 AS AAPL_265598_30min_roc_2
    FROM 
        AAPL_265598_15min m15
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM AAPL_265598_30min m30
        WHERE DateTime < m15.DateTime AND
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, m30.DateTime, m15.DateTime) >= 30
        ORDER BY m30.DateTime DESC
    ) m30
    WHERE 
            m15.DateTime IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.MonthNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.DayNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.roc_1 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.roc_2 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.MonthNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.DayNr IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.roc_1 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m30.roc_2 IS NOT NULL 
        AND m15.hypo_upordown7bars IS NOT NULL
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT t15.DateTime,
    t15.MonthNr, t15.DayNr,
    t15.roc_1, t15.roc_2,
    t30.roc_1, t30.roc_2
FROM AAPL_265598_15min AS t15
JOIN AAPL_265598_30min AS t30 ON t30.DateTime
    BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -46, t15.DateTime)
    AND DATEADD(MINUTE, -16, t15.DateTime)
ORDER BY t15.DateTime
```

(you better have `DateTime` field indexed in both tables ;-)